# links not working on web server

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink

i have developed a php application which is running perfect on local server. when i deployed the application on web server the links are not working

1)  my site is "abc.myapplication.com"  (abc is subdomain)

i defined following variable in config file

```
 define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

ROOT_PATH variable shows /home/punjabfo/public_html/abc (which is perfect)

for link i used following code

```
<a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH . "addrecord.php"; ?>">Add Record</a>
```

link should go to "abc.myapplication.com/addrecord.php" but link go to

```
"abc.myapplication.com/home/punjabfo/public_html/abcaddrecord.php"
```

i tried a lot but could not fin the issue. please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: just used define("ROOT_PATH", "/");

Comment: I don't think this is correct answer, as it does not explain what was the real problem. Even more, your advice is to use 9 character constant instead of a single slash. HACK!

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with Keeping It Simple

```
<a href="addrecord.php">Add Record</a>
```

Let the server do all the work, as it gets it right and you do less messing around.

Comment: Also, using full paths create a relocation nightmare.

Comment: I would love to know why not. You quoted that on your local server `define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` generated `/home/punjabfo/public_html/addrecord.php`. So I assume public_html is your DocumentRoot. Therefore `<a href="addrecord.php">Add Record</a>` is a valid replacement that should work on any web server. `PS that does not look like a Windows directoy structure so I assume you are not using `WAMP Server`

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "addrecord.php"; ?>">Add Record</a>
```

Comment: it go to the "abc.myapplication.com/IPADDRESSaddrecord.php"

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   
echo 'http://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . '/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']". **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** stands for the root directory on the server (dir-path). What you need, is the URL and not the file-system-path.

Take a look on

```
<?php 
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($_SERVER);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to do

```
<a href="/addrecord.php">Add Record</a>
```

Of course you do not need `ROOT_PATH` in the URL. What you do is returning **full path** of the file, instead of **link**. And btw, full path is incorrect itself, as you forgot slash before `addrecord.php`.